# Check scalable matrix diagonals for identical string

Tags: java, matrix

I am creating a scalable TicTacToe program, and I am running into an issue when trying to check the diagonals for a string.

I was able to check the rows by using this method:

```
    public boolean checkRowsForWin(String b){
    //Check all the rows for a winner
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
            if (globalGrid[y][x].equals(b)){
                inRow++;
                if (inRow >= neededToWin){
                    return true;
                }
            }else{
                inRow = 0;
            }
        }
        inRow = 0;
    }
    inRow = 0;
    return false;
}
```

I have tried a combination of for loops and if statements, and my last modification is this below. This worked if the diagonal included the top right corner only, when I need it to check even if the diagonal isn't in a corner.

```
    public boolean checkDiagForWin(String b, int c, int d){
    for (int x = c, y = d; x < size && y < size; x++, y++){
        if (globalGrid[y][x].equals(b)){
            inRow++;
            if (inRow >= neededToWin){
                return true;
            }
        }
        else{
            inRow = 0;
        }
        inRow = 0;
        for (int x2 = size - 1, y2 = 0; x2 >=0 && y2 < size; x2--, y2++){
            if (globalGrid[y2][x2].equals(b)){
                inRow++;
                if (inRow >= neededToWin){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else{
                inRow = 0;
            }
        }
        inRow = 0;
    }   
    inRow = 0;
    return false;
}
```

The amount in a row and the size of the board can change, so it isn't as simple as checking just two adjacent to the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the process starting at every possible position, one possible implementation could be:

A function to start the check process at every position:

```
public boolean checkDiagonals(String b) {
    /* Check the diagonals starting in every position */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (checkDiagonalForWin(b, i, j) || checkOtherDiagonalForWin(b, i, j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are the functions to check the diagonals starting in some position:

```
public boolean checkDiagonalForWin(String b, int row, int col){

    for (int inRow = 0; row  < size && col < size; row++, col++) {
        //Check all the rows for a winner
        if (globalGrid[row][col].equals(b)){
            inRow++;
            if (inRow >= neededToWin){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            inRow = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkOtherDiagonalForWin(String b, int row, int col){        
    for (int inRow = 0; row  < size && col >= 0; row++, col--) {
        //Check all the rows for a winner
        if (globalGrid[row][col].equals(b)){
            inRow++;
            if (inRow >= neededToWin){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            inRow = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works, however it only checks if it is in the corner, while the diagonal could be anywhere on the board (for larger boards, such as 8).

Comment: @Tanner I missed that requirement, I updated my answer accordingly.